# for loop in form and input type all the same angular

Tags: html, angular

[image]

I for loop in my form and when I type it type in every input. (Look at the photo I attached)
Here's my app.components.html:

```
  <ul class="border">

    <li *ngFor="let cake of cakes; let idx = index">
      <img class="d-inline-block" (click)="getCake(idx)" src="{{cake.url}}" alt="{{cake.id}}" width="250"
        height="250">
      <form class="d-inline-block form-rate">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="rating" [(ngModel)]="newRating.rating" class="custom-select">
            <option selected value="1">1 stars</option>
            <option value="2">2 stars</option>
            <option value="3">3 stars</option>
            <option value="4">4 stars</option>
            <option value="5">5 stars</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea name="comment" [(ngModel)]="newRating.comment" class="form-control" id="rate-comment" rows="4"
            placeholder="Type your comment here"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group clearfix">
          <button class="btn btn-primary float-right btn-sm" (click)="ratingSubmit(cake._id)">Rate!</button>
        </div>

      </form>

    </li>

  </ul>
```

And this is my app.components.ts:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpService } from "./http.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "cake";
  cakes = [];

  newCake: any;
  newRating = { rating: "", comment: "" };
  selectedCake;
  avg;

  constructor(private _httpService: HttpService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCakesFromService();
    this.newCake = { name: "", url: "" };
  }

  getCakesFromService() {
    let observable = this._httpService.getCakes();
    observable.subscribe((data) => {
      this.cakes = data["data"];
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    let observable = this._httpService.addCake(this.newCake);
    observable.subscribe((data) => {
      this.newCake = { name: "", url: "" };
      this.getCakesFromService();
    });
  }

  ratingSubmit(cakeId) {
    let observable = this._httpService.addRating(this.newRating, cakeId);
    observable.subscribe((data) => {});
    this.newRating = { rating: "", comment: "" };
    this.getCakesFromService();
  }

  getCake(idx) {
    this.selectedCake = this.cakes[idx];
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedCake.ratings.length; i++) {
      sum += this.selectedCake.ratings[i].rating;
    }
    this.avg = sum / this.selectedCake.ratings.length;
  }
}
```

Just updated my code and add some more codes into it.
I tried to console.log(this.newRating) but it came out an object with empty string

```
{rating: "", comment: ""}
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: You can bind comment and ratings to cake object itself. You need to use `cake.rating` instead of `newRating.rating` and `cake.comment` instead of `newRating.comment`. You need to do some changes into `ratingSubmit()` method as well.

Comment: How to change this.newRating = { rating: "", comment: "" }; to achieve what you said?

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind `comment` and `rating` to cake object itself. You need to use `cake.newRating` instead of `newRating.rating` and `cake.newComment` instead of `newRating.comment`.

**app.components.html**

```
<ul class="border">

    <li *ngFor="let cake of cakes; let idx = index">
      <img class="d-inline-block" (click)="getCake(idx)" src="{{cake.url}}" alt="{{cake.id}}" width="250"
        height="250">
      <form class="d-inline-block form-rate">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="rating" [(ngModel)]="cake.newRating" class="custom-select">
            <option selected value="1">1 stars</option>
            <option value="2">2 stars</option>
            <option value="3">3 stars</option>
            <option value="4">4 stars</option>
            <option value="5">5 stars</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea name="comment" [(ngModel)]="cake.newComment" class="form-control" id="rate-comment" rows="4"
            placeholder="Type your comment here"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group clearfix">
          <button class="btn btn-primary float-right btn-sm" (click)="ratingSubmit(cake)">Rate!</button>
        </div>

      </form>

    </li>

  </ul>
```

You need to do some changes into `ratingSubmit()` method as well.

**app.components.ts**

```
ratingSubmit(cake) {
    let observable = this._httpService.addRating({'rating' : cake.newRating, 'comment': cake.newComment}, cake._id);
    observable.subscribe((data) => {
    // after successful submission of ratings do following.
    cake.newRating = ''; 
    cake.newComment: '';
    this.getCakesFromService();
    });
  }
```

Comment: {'' : cake.newRating, '': cake.newComment} at this line i have a duplicate identifier error

Comment: addRating(newRating, cakeId) {
    console.log(newRating);
    return this._http.post(`/ratings/${cakeId}`, newRating);
  }

Comment: my http.service.ts expect 2 arguments and what can I add into that?

Comment: Yes. I have added the json into the `ratingSubmit` method. pls check that.

Comment: Thanks alot really really really appreciate it

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps you. I will really appreciate if you accept the answer and upvote it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping correctly, but it is binding each input to the same variable: `newRating.rating`. That is why each input is showing up the same.

Fixing this is a little bit more complicated, and I don't know enough about what you are trying to do to tell you exactly how to do it.

One guess I have is binding it to the exact cake:

```
<select name="rating" [(ngModel)]="cakes[idx].rating" class="custom-select">
```

But again, that might not be what you're trying to accomplish. You may have to create an array of `newRating` that you can then bind to based on the index of the for loop.

Anyways, I hope that helps. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks! I tried and when i submitted the form the value of rating and comment didnt create.

Comment: Try console.log on the value of the form when you submit. What gets logged to the console?

Comment: it's an empty string ""